# My screens flicker and then go black when using graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

My screens flicker and then go black when using graphics card. I can run my PC for hours fine but as soon as i load up a game or anything using my graphics card intensely it stops working. I have tried reinstalling the games, nothing. Reinstalling windows, nothing. So on a clean PC i tried it with my original graphics card, crash. Tried with other graphics card, works fine. What could my problem be? I have used this graphics card no problem for a year and a half and usually runs the games fine.

Graphics card that doesnt work - MSI Radeon R9 270

Comment: Are you updated to the latest drivers? What version?

Comment: Like Cory said, I would definitely check on the drivers, and just to be safe, make sure the previous drivers (for the original graphics card) is uninstalled as well.  [AMD'S Website](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) has the driver you will need

Comment: Yes i  had the latest drivers. I was playing games and it just randomly stopped working between ending one game and starting another, didn't exit the program or anything